# How can I watch and log changes in my files?

Tags: windows, filesystems

Some of my files mysteriously and randomly changes. I would like to know what/who caused it. Is it possible to watch the files and log any changes (like time, content before/after, and if possible the responsible process) in Windows XP? Or if not possible, is there a tool which does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Process Monitor utility will do that. Read all about it at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645. There
are also lots of more narrowly focused applications available to monitor directory changes. A Powershell script is available
at http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b which will allow you to script some
desired action when the directory is modified.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. With the professional versions of [Windows 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300549) and [up](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/advanced-security-auditing-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx), you can use [Security Auditing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399) to monitor and log file and folder access and modification.

If you need more advanced features, you may need third-party tools. In [Vista](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions) and [up](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions), you can compare different versions of files with the [Previous Versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) functionality. It is also available in XP SP2.